# NodeJS fs.watch is not reacting to changes inside a Docker Container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, fs

The idea of the following code is to react to changes in files inside a folder. When I run this code on my macOS everything works as executed.

```
let fs = require("fs");

let options = {
    encoding: 'buffer'
}

fs.watch('.', options, function(eventType, filename) {

    if(filename)
    {
        console.log(filename.toString());
    }

});
```

Inside a Docker Container on the other hand the code does not react to file changes. I run the code in the following way:

`docker run -it --rm --name $(basename $(pwd)) -v $(pwd):/app -w /app node:slim sh -c 'node index'`

Is there an option to use with Docker to allow system notifications for file changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New answer**

Initially i advised Gulp (see bottom of the updated post with old answer). It did not worked because you tried to use it programatically, when Gulp is task runner and have own usage patterns, which i did not described. Since you need something specific, i have very simple, surely working solution for you.

It uses one of modules used by gulp called [gaze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze) - module which have approx 1.7m downloads per week. Its working, for sure on every system.

`npm install gaze --save`

To make it work lets create `index.js` in your root folder (which will be mounted to your `app` folder inside of the docker, and then just follow basic instruction given in module README:

```
 var gaze = require('gaze');

 // Watch all .js files/dirs in process.cwd() 
 gaze('**/*.js', function(err, watcher) {
 // Files have all started watching 
 // watcher === this 
 console.log('Watching files...');

 // Get all watched files 
 var watched = this.watched();

 // On file changed 
 this.on('changed', function(filepath) {
  console.log(filepath + ' was changed');
 });

 // On file added 
 this.on('added', function(filepath) {
   console.log(filepath + ' was added');
 });

  // On file deleted 
 this.on('deleted', function(filepath) {
  console.log(filepath + ' was deleted');
 });

 // On changed/added/deleted 
 this.on('all', function(event, filepath) {
  console.log(filepath + ' was ' + event);
 });

  // Get watched files with relative paths 
   var files = this.relative();
  });
```

Now lets run your command:

`docker run -it --rm --name $(basename $(pwd)) -v $(pwd):/app -w /app node sh -c 'node index'`

What we have upon changes - Linux outpud, but this works for Mac OS too.

```
   blackstork@linux-uksg:~/WebstormProjects/SO/case1> docker run -it --rm --name $(basename $(pwd)) -v $(pwd):/app -w /app node sh -c 'node index'
   Watching files...
   /app/bla was changed
   /app/foobar.js was changed
```

**Old answer.**

> You can do it with gulp. 
>    Gulpfile.js
>
> ```
>  const gulp = require('gulp');
>
>  gulp.task( 'watch' , ()=>{
>     return gulp.watch(['app/**'], ['doStuff']);
>  });
>
>  gulp.task( 'doStuff', cb => {
>    console.log('stuff');
>    //do stuff
>    cb();
>   });
> ```
>
> So far such approach worked for me (of course you can build much more
>   complex things, but if find using gulp conventient for different
>   filesystem tasks).

Comment: Hmm, you are just running the `watch` app from Linux. I'm looking for a solution where I'm not fixed to the content of the operating system. So it works out of the box.

Comment: It's not from linux. It's pure Node.js. It works in any OS, and it just node.js module that uses node.js streams (it create readable/duplex node.js stream and watches changes).

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the staring "watch" means. From Gulp documentation: `The name of the task. Tasks that you want to run from the command line should not have spaces in them.`

Comment: gulp.watch is implemented with node.js streams, which implement node `EventEmitter` interface. They have nothing in particulat towards one OS or another. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb

Comment: same could be done with node.js streams. And I think you have misunderstanding of what gulp task is. Gulp taks perfectly being run on windows. all you need is `npm install -g gulp`, install it locally, and have what i wrote in `gulpfile.js`. It's pure node.js.

Comment: you using it not correctly, then. Perhaps i provided not enough information for you. I'll check at home the missing parts and will update my post, but I am sure i have this  approach working in many places, inside of the docker containers. I'll notify about update, and if it will work  with more information provided please remove your "vote down". I am just trying to help.

Comment: Of course I will bump if works :) I'm not a neanderthal ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer and provided more simple to use solution. Hope that helps. Cheers :)

Comment: Gaze is doing the trick, wasn't' aware of this module. Thank you for the help :)